# Perl Array dereference not working properly while passing it as an argument to a subroutine

Tags: arrays, perl, reference, dereference

I am passing an array as ref to a sub. There I have to add values to it, but its not working. my code is:

```
my @scalarArray1 = ();

sub CompareScalers() {
    fillScalarArray( $_[0], \@scalarArray1 );    #pass arrays by ref
}

sub fillScalarArray() {
    my $filename = $_[0];                        #first file name as input file
    open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename ) or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
    my @array = @{ $_[1] };
    while ( my $row = <$fh> ) {
        push( @array, $row );
    }
}
```

The debug print at end of while loop for the size of arrays is as follows:

```
 DB<29> p $#scalarArray1
-1
 DB<30> p $#array
1551
```

Comment: Why have you [prototyped](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Prototypes) your subs to allow zero arguments each?  That seems at worst mistaken and at best quite misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`my @array = @{$_[1]}` makes a copy of the array. When you push items onto the copy, the original array is not affected.

I assume you want your function to actually modify the array pointed to by the reference. To do that, eliminate the `my @array = ...` line and change your `push` calls to be like the following, which uses the reference without copying:

```
push (@{$_[1]} , $row);
```

For readability, you can assign the array reference to a named scalar variable and use that instead:

```
my $arrayRef = $_[1];
push @{$arrayRef}, $row;
```

Comment: Thanks, got it... i checked the references and both had difference. Thanks for the input. This is the correct answer.

Comment: Can we name referenced arrays ? like my $array = @{$_[0]} , and later on use the array name in our sub ? just asking for readability purpose.

Comment: Yes. Added an example to the answer.

Comment: if using Perl v5.14 or greater, you can push directly onto the reference.